# How do I get rid of spiders inside my car?

Tags: hyundai, car, cleaning

I often have spider webs on my right side mirror and in the handle to open my boot. I've seen a spider on the boot handle once, but when I tried to catch it, it crawled inside the handle somewhere (difficult to see, as it's one of those handles that's under the logo). I'm pretty sure the spider/s are still there, as even after cleaning the webs away, they come back soon.

I've never actually seen a spider *inside* the car (i.e. where the driver and passengers sit), and no webs inside either, so I'm guessing the spiders are inside the mirror / handle.

The car is a Hyundai i30.

Comment: Try the peppermint and water. I live in the states and have regular issues with cars I leave outside. I rebuild engines and cars can sit for a quite a while sometimes. I had a 2007 Hyundai Tiburon that was left in a shop; Spiders infested it. I used Peppermint extract in the AC vents and sprayed around areas I thought they could have gotten in. After that I left a "Spider trap" I found at a hardware store in there. Haven't had a problem since. Good luck!

Comment: The only reliable way of dealing with spiders I've ever heard of is nuclear weaponry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method is to tent the vehicle with a tarp and then use and insect fogger spray under the tarp. This is used in areas with high numbers of poisonous insects by repair technicians who are tasked with repairing cars that have been little used.

Answer (score 4):

I use a mixture of 1 cup of peppermint oil to 1 gallon warm water in garden sprayer to deter spiders in my house. I have seen fewer spiders since doing this, hope this helps.